# Property 'representedObject' with type 'AnyObject?' cannot override a property with type 'Any?'

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift3

I've run into an issue trying to upgrade the following code to Swift 3.

How could I fix this?

```
   @IBAction func Quit(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        NSApplication.shared().terminate(self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        //INSERT DATE & TIME
        labeldate.stringValue = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: DateFormatter.Style.full, timeStyle: DateFormatter.Style.none)

    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
```

It says:

> Property 'representedObject' with type 'AnyObject?' cannot override a property with type 'Any?'

What could I use instead?

Comment: In swift 3 AnyObject is replaced with Any

Comment: Read the error. Then look at the Swift 3 documentation for the `representedObject` variable. The change becomes obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the following in your code

```
 override var representedObject: Any? {
   didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
   }
 }
```